# Transgender but not transitioning?

Tags: single-word-requests, sexual-minorities

Inspired by [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/73610/23657) on CSE 
I am asking is there a term to describe a transgender individual who chooses not to physically transition to how they identify?

Lots of terminology is offered in this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitioning_(transgender)) page for example:

Passing, transitioning, going stealth, going full time, social transitioning.

So is there an easy way of saying that one is resisting transition for the sake of not alienating friends and family?

Comment: This isn't really a question about English, even though the word(s) you come up with may be in English. It's probably a term of art of the LGBTQ+ community.

Comment: @Robusto all of the words and terminology suggested by LGBTQ+ community necessarily become English language and usage terms.

Comment: Maybe they do, and maybe they don't. It's going to be too early to tell for quite some time, which is why I would confine them for the present to terms of art.

Comment: @Robusto I don't know if I'd call them terms of art.  Rather, I'd call them personal decisions for now.  And, as the language evolves, I suspect we'll start to see conventions come to light.

Comment: @DavidM: A "term of art" is merely a word that has a particular meaning in a particular context. I think that applies here.

Comment: @Robusto I understand the meaning.  I'm just suggesting that there's not enough agreement in the community to even call it a term of art yet . . .

Comment: The way of referring to human individuals has been around for thousands of years. It's called a 'name'. I refer to people by their name, either to them or about them, and I don't bother much about all the intricate details. It's kind of none of my business. And, often, none of my interest.

Comment: To be fair, I don't think anyone is consulting purveyors of the English language  on such matters. In this respect, they act as historians. No one asked Oxford or Merriam-Webster if "dad joke" or "lol" were acceptable, the publishers just capture what has been recognized by the masses. When the world has spoken, someone will have to let the dictionaries know.

Comment: I thought this kind of concealment was called being in the closet. The reason or reasons are many and diverse, and are unlikely to combine with the condition or circumstance to produce a single word.

Comment: When you say "one is resisting transition for the sake of not alienating friends and family" do you mean they're not coming out as transgender at all despite how they identify mentally? Because if they're "passing" then won't that alienate their intolerant friends?

Comment: @nnnnnn   1 yes 2  if they are “ passing”  they are perceived to be the gender they identify as.  So I am not referring to individuals  who are “passing” unless your definition of “passing” means a trans person who is “passing” as a “normal” person  among  peers who have no reason to think they are trans. In that case yes. I think

Answer (score 3):

You may be looking for the term **non-op**, as defined by the [Gender Wiki](https://gender.wikia.org/wiki/Non-Op) as:

> Non-op refers to those who do not wish to have gender confirmation surgery.

(Compare *pre-op* and *post-op*.)

However, *non-op* still includes some people who physically alter themselves through other means, such as hormones or [binding](https://gender.wikia.org/wiki/Binding).

Comment: Thanks for addressing the question. Gender wiki lists a few reasons one may be non-op. Could I assume that one may be non op for reasons such as not wanting to alienate family and friends? Non op for religious reasons?

Answer (score 2):

[**Transgender person**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transgender) still describes these people rather nicely.

If you wish to state that they have not yet disclosed their identify to the world at large, you'd call them [**closeted** or **in the closet**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closeted).

> Closeted and in the closet are adjectives for lesbian, gay, bisexual, transgender etc. (LGBTQ+) people who have not disclosed their sexual orientation or gender identity and aspects thereof, including sexual identity and sexual behavior. It can also be used to describe anyone who is hiding part of their identity because of social pressure.

The decision to transition physically is not what makes them transgender, but rather the personal feeling that their biological gender is not their gender identity.  Many transgender people will never choose to make a transition.

Some choose to use the term [**transexual**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transsexual) for those who have (or wish to) transition physically, but there is some disagreement on this nomenclature.

---

As an aside which is off-topic to the OP's question, but is always worth addressing in these types of questions.

When it comes to matters of gender identity, sexual identity/orientation, name, ethnicity, or any other matter of personal identity I use the following rule:

> I'll call you whatever you wish to be called.

I think that most people would welcome the question if it's asked in a respectful manner.

The use of pronouns is a minefield all its own.

When speaking to someone, this is rarely an issue, as *you* is ungendered in English.  But, we frequently need to speak *about* someone, often in his or her presence.

Third party pronouns are more complex.  Some people prefer to be called by their identity, some prefer to be called by their outward appearance (and this can change with things like transvestitism), and yet others prefer genderless pronouns (Shim, sher, etc. etc.).  Using *they* seems like an awkward appropriation of the plural.

Here too, I repeat the advice of inquiring as to a person's preference.

If you are unable to ask someone about their preference, writing about a historical figure for example, then I'd recommend going with their outward appearance.

Comment: What I find weird in all this is the pronoun thing. the idea that someone can tell me how to address them when I am **talking about them** and not **to them**. No one ever seems to point that out. The only way to address someone directly in English is "you". What have I missed?

Comment: @Lambie See my edit.  I feel that I've addressed this.

Comment: The question is asking for a term that a transgender person would use for their situation of internally identifying as other than birth gender but determining not to transition because they do not wish to have others view them differently. It is not asking how others should address transgender persons.

Comment: @Kris you'd still call them transgender. If they're *in the closet* about it, you'd say that.  *Closeted* is the term that most of the LBGTQ+ community uses. My point in the post was that regardless of whether or not you've chosen to transition you're still what you are.  How to refer to people includes how to address them.

Comment: @Kris  Edited to reflect my comment.